# logstash-2.2.2, windows, IIS log file format

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

when I'm parsing iis log file in UTF-8 format I'm getting below error and When I'm parsing log file using ANSI format there is nothing working Logstash just display message on console " Logstash startup completed". There is almost 1000 files on my server i can't change each file format from ANSI to UTF-8. Can you please help where I need to change in my config file. I'm also attaching debug file when I'm parsing files on UTF-8 format. I'm using elastic search on same box and its completely working fine. I'm also able to telnet port 9200 with 127.0.0.1.

Log sample:

```
2016-03-26T05:40:40.764Z WIN-AK44913P759 2016-03-24 00:16:31 W3SVC20 ODSANDBOXWEB01 172.x.x.x GET /healthmonitor.axd - 80 - 172.x.x.x HTTP/1.1 - - - www.xyz.net 200 0 0 4698 122 531
```

stdout output:

```
{
  "message" => "2016-03-24 04:43:02 W3SVC20 ODSANDBOXWEB01 172.x.x.x GET /healthmonitor.axd - 80 - 172.x.x.x HTTP/1.1 - - - www.xyz.net 200 0 0 4698 122 703\r",
  "@version" => "1",
  "@timestamp" => "2016-03-26T05:42:15.045Z",
  "path" => "C:\\IISLogs/u_ex160324.log",
  "host" => "WIN-AK44913P759",
  "type" => "IISLog",
  "tags" => [
     [0] "_grokparsefailure"
  ]
}
```

Below is my logstash conf file configuration

```
input {
  file {
    type => "IISLog"
    path => "C:\IISLogs/u_ex*.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  #ignore log comments
  if [message] =~ "^#" {
    drop {}
  }
  grok {
    match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{WORD:iisSite} %{IPORHOST:site} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:page} %{NOTSPACE:querystring} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IPORHOST:clienthost} %{NOTSPACE:useragent} %{NOTSPACE:referer} %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:subresponse} %{NUMBER:scstatus} %{NUMBER:bytes:int} %{NUMBER:timetaken:int}"]
  }
  #Set the Event Timesteamp from the log
  date {
    match => [ "log_timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    timezone => "Etc/UCT"
  }
  useragent {
    source=> "useragent"
    prefix=> "browser"
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "log_timestamp"]
  }
}
# output logs to console and to elasticsearch
output {
  stdout {}
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The _grokparsefailure tag means that your grok pattern didn't match your input.  It looks like you're intending the pattern to skip the first two fields, which is fine.

Then, looking at the next four fields, I see:

```
2016-03-24 00:16:31 W3SVC20 ODSANDBOXWEB01 172.1.1.1
```

but your pattern is looking for

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{WORD:iisSite} %{IPORHOST:site} %{WORD:method}
```

You haven't accounted for the IP address (since ODSANDBOXWEB01 is going into [site]).

Building grok patterns is a deliberate, iterative process.  Start at the [debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/).  Enter a sample input line and then add grok patterns - one at a time! - until the entire line has been matched.

Also, when you obfuscate your data, please leave it as valid data.  Changing the ip to 172.x.x.x means that it won't match the %{IP} pattern without us having to figure out what you did. I changed it to 172.1.1.1 in this example.

Comment: Hi Alain, Thansk for the update. In my case 172.x.x.x means is the normal IP address format. Is there any help available to build Grok pattern . I'm little new with Elastic search & logstash.

Comment: I knew what 172.x.x.x meant, but since that input will never match %{IP}, you make those of us who are trying to help you do more work to debug your pattern.  If you had changed it to some other valid IP, it would be easier to debug.  As for learning grok, perhaps start here: http://svops.com/blog/introduction-to-logstash-grok-patterns/